# T/F: If $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ and $F$ is differentiable, then $f$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus

T/F: If $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ and $F$ is differentiable, then $f$ is continuous.

I think this is false but I'm not sure how to give an example. Maybe $f$ as the sign function and then take $a = 1$ and $F(x) = x$ ?

Comment: notice that you can change $f$ on a countable set and then $F(x)$ remains unchanged.

Comment: Was my example correct?

Comment: When you say “differentiable” and “continuous”, do you mean *at $a$* or *for all $x$* or something else?

Comment: @Rita No, the integral of the sign function is $|x|$, which is not everywhere differentiable. Using clark's suggestion, try $f(x)=1_{\Bbb Z}(x)$, the indicator function of the integers (which is Riemann-integrable with $F(x)=0$).

Comment: Wasn't mentioned but I think for all $x$

Comment: But Matthew, for $x \geq 1 = a$ the integral is just $x$

Answer (score 3):

Your counterexample is not valid.  Because if $f(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x)$ then $F(x) = |x| + C$, which is not differentiable at $0$.  So you can't use it as a counterexample for $F$ differentiable $\implies$ $f$ continuous.

Try this: Let $f(x) = 0$ if $x\neq a$, otherwise $f(a) = 1$.  Then $F(x) = 0$ for all $x$, meaning $F'(x) = 0$ for all $x$, but $f$ is not continuous at $a$.